# Move object within canvas boundary limit

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to limit the moving object within the canvas but i am getting some difficulty in moving the object in the limit area on top and left side and when i scale the object bigger then also i am not able to limit the moving object on left and top sides of the canvas

```js
canvas.observe("object:moving", function(e) {
  var obj = e.target;
  // if object is too big ignore
  if(obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height || obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width) {
    return;
  }

  var halfw = obj.currentWidth/2;
  var halfh = obj.currentHeight/2;
  var bounds = {
    tl: {x: halfw, y:halfh},
    br: {x: obj.canvas.width-halfw, y: obj.canvas.height-halfh}
  };

  // top-left  corner
  if(obj.top < bounds.tl.y || obj.left < bounds.tl.x) {
    obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, bounds.tl.y);
    obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, bounds.tl.x )
  }
        
  // bot-right corner
  if(obj.top > bounds.br.y || obj.left > bounds.br.x) {
    obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, bounds.br.y);
    obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, bounds.br.x)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the below code in your js file and change the value of scale X(left) and Y(top) according to your canvas height and width.

```
// canvas moving limit 

canvas.observe("object:moving", function(e){
      var obj = e.target;
         // if object is too big ignore

        var halfw = obj.currentWidth/2;
        var halfh = obj.currentHeight/2;
        var bounds = {tl: {x: halfw, y:halfh},
            br: {x: obj.canvas.width , y: obj.canvas.height }
        };

        // top-left  corner



            // alert("text");
        if(obj.top < bounds.tl.y || obj.left < bounds.tl.x){
            obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, '10'  );
            obj.left = Math.max(obj.left , '50' ) 
        }


        // bot-right corner
        if(obj.top > bounds.br.y || obj.left > bounds.br.x ){
            obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, '360'  );  
            obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, '470' )  
        }

});
// end canvas moving limit
```

Comment: Is there anyway to force objects to go outside canvas ?

Comment: ask question on stack

Comment: It's simply yes or no question, if yes then how ? No need for extra question. Stack has very egoistic community moderator, they close the question with negative, If I simply ask ques.

Comment: Slightly dated, but after I made the needed changes, it worked. Observe is no longer a function, and height and width are now attributes, not methods you have to get.

Answer (score 64):

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
  var obj = e.target;
  // if object is too big ignore
  if(obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height || obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width){
    return;
  }
  obj.setCoords();
  // top-left  corner
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < 0 || obj.getBoundingRect().left < 0){
    obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
    obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
  }
  // bot-right corner
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height  > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width  > obj.canvas.width){
    obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
    obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
  }
});
```

Comment: Best solution I've seen.

Comment: If you need to allow the objects to be moved partly outside the canvas bounding, see my enhanced function below

Comment: Nice! It it possible to override the fabric function so this would affect all fabric canvasses?

Answer (score 7):

Here you can find solution:-

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.selection = false;

fabric.Object.prototype.set({
    transparentCorners: false,
    cornerColor: 'red',
    cornerSize: 12,
    padding: 0
});
text = new fabric.Text('Sample',{
    top: canvas.height/2,
    left: canvas.width/2,
    fill: '#000000'
});

canvas.add(text);
canvas.setActiveObject(text);

canvas.observe('object:scaling', function (e) {
    var obj = e.target;
  if(obj.getHeight() > obj.canvas.height || obj.getWidth() > obj.canvas.width){
    obj.setScaleY(obj.originalState.scaleY);
    obj.setScaleX(obj.originalState.scaleX);        
  }
  obj.setCoords();
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top - (obj.cornerSize / 2) < 0 || 
     obj.getBoundingRect().left -  (obj.cornerSize / 2) < 0) {
    obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top + (obj.cornerSize / 2));
    obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left + (obj.cornerSize / 2));    
  }
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height + obj.cornerSize  > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width + obj.cornerSize  > obj.canvas.width) {

    obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top - obj.cornerSize / 2);
    obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left - obj.cornerSize /2);    
  }
});

canvas.observe('object:moving', function (e) {
    var obj = e.target;
  if(obj.getHeight() > obj.canvas.height || obj.getWidth() > obj.canvas.width){
    obj.setScaleY(obj.originalState.scaleY);
    obj.setScaleX(obj.originalState.scaleX);        
  }
  obj.setCoords();
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top - (obj.cornerSize / 2) < 0 || 
     obj.getBoundingRect().left -  (obj.cornerSize / 2) < 0) {
    obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top + (obj.cornerSize / 2));
    obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left + (obj.cornerSize / 2));    
  }
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height + obj.cornerSize  > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width + obj.cornerSize  > obj.canvas.width) {

    obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top - obj.cornerSize / 2);
    obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left - obj.cornerSize /2);    
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jw1827fm/1/

Comment: The scale did not work for me with version 1.7.11.
First you need to build the fabric canvas with `{stateful : true,}`.
second I had to use `_stateProperties` instead of `originalState`.
Third you need to `obj.saveState();` after these changes.

Answer (score 1):

I just Modified Balaji's code a little bit works better now

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
    var obj = e.target;

     // if object is too big ignore
    if(obj.getScaledHeight() > obj.canvas.height || obj.getScaledWidth() > obj.canvas.width){
        return;
    }        
    obj.setCoords();        
    // top-left  corner
    if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < 0 || obj.getBoundingRect().left < 0){
        obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
        obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
    }
    // bot-right corner
    if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height  > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width  > obj.canvas.width){
        obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
        obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
    }});
```

Answer (score 1):

As i needed this, here is my overworked function based on Balaji's code to set a offset, so objects can be only partly showed within the canvas.

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
      var obj = e.target;

      // if object is too big ignore
      if(obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height || obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width){
          return;
      }        

      // set offset for moving out the canvas (20 % of object persists in canvas)
      var offsetWidth = obj.getBoundingRect().width * 0.8;
      var offsetHeight = obj.getBoundingRect().height * 0.8;

      obj.setCoords();        

      // top-left  corner
      if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < -offsetHeight || obj.getBoundingRect().left < -offsetWidth){
          obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-(obj.getBoundingRect().top+offsetHeight));
          obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-(obj.getBoundingRect().left+offsetWidth));
      }
      // bot-right corner
      if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height  > obj.canvas.height + offsetHeight || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width  > obj.canvas.width + offsetWidth){
          obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top+offsetHeight);
          obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left+offsetWidth);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modified a bit too the code of Balaji and Surya T so it take care fully now of canvas zoom setting.

```
   _self.layer.on('object:moving', function (e) {
        var obj = e.target;

        obj.setCoords();
        var curZoom = obj.canvas.getZoom();

        //
        // if object is too big ignore
        if(obj.getScaledHeight() > obj.canvas.height || obj.getScaledWidth() > obj.canvas.width){
            return;
        }

        // top-left  corner
        if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < 0 || obj.getBoundingRect().left < 0){
            obj.top = Math.max(obj.top*curZoom, obj.top*curZoom-obj.getBoundingRect().top)/curZoom;
            obj.left = Math.max(obj.left*curZoom, obj.left*curZoom-obj.getBoundingRect().left)/curZoom;
        }
        // bot-right corner
        if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height  > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width  > obj.canvas.width){
            obj.top = Math.min(obj.top*curZoom, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top*curZoom-obj.getBoundingRect().top)/curZoom;
            obj.left = Math.min(obj.left*curZoom, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left*curZoom-obj.getBoundingRect().left)/curZoom;
        }
    });
```